# Keep angle between path nodes

Tags: inkscape, path

I have a path consisting of three nodes where two nodes are in a 45° angle. Now I want to shorten the angled part and keep the angle.

[image]

Is there a way to snap two nodes and drag them across a specific angle?

Answer (score 1):

You could duplicate the object <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and do *Object > Object to guides* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, and then enable snapping, snap nodes paths and handles, and snap cusp nodes, and snap guides. Then *Edit > Lock all guides*.

Then it's just a matter of moving the node until it snaps to where you want it.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped for a modified key (ctrl, alt, etc.) but no such luck. One method is to drag a guide diagonally to the middle node with snap turned on. As you move the lowest node, it will tend to snap to the guide.

One advantage of this method is you can set the guide angle to any value.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround 1:

If you drag a shape to different size with the normal selection tool and holding Ctrl at the same time the size changes proportionally. That means all angles stay intact.

I guess scaling the strokes is prevented in the preferences. If that's true you must set the stroke width temporarily to zero because in Inkscape the stroke width unfortunately is counted to object size and that ruins the proportionality. In Illustrator that does not happen.

Workaround 2:

Duplicate the existing line. If you have snap to path ON you can easily move the endpoint along the duplicate if you make it smaller. Delete the unnecessary version. If you try to make a line longer you can draw a new line (zero stroke width) move it or scale it proportionally longer, send it to back and drag the original endpoint along the line.

Learn to reach shapes and lines via the Objects panel. There you can easily for ex lock those parts which do not stand accidental edits and you can select parts inside groups and under clipping masks.

Comment: I did something similar. It works, but seems like a complicated method for such an easy operation. Powerpoint and libre draw can natively snap angles, direction. I do not understand why simple operations are so unnecessary complicated in such a powerful software. Thank you for the tip with the object locking.

Comment: Workarounds are needed in every program that I have used for drawing. None of them unfortunately contains everything that users can want.

Comment: @v3xX INexperienced computer users often think that features of software groups are somehow set in stone. They are not, having used hundreds of software i recognize that: Features are random, every feature you implement affects the whole so by making a feature you make it impossible for you to have a other feature. But that said i think inkscape is not feature complete or very well composed. I mean even their nase implementation of snapping is a bit flawed. But inkscape is open source you can implement this id you want to.